# Why isn't Python autocompletion working in gvim?

Tags: python, vim

My system: WIN7 +GVIM, all 64 bits.

1. I have downloaded pydiction-1.2.zip, and extract it into

   ```
   D:\vim73-x64\vimfiles\ftplugin\pydiction
   ```
2. I have edited _vimrc.

   ```
   filetype plugin on
   set filetype=python
   let g:pydiction_location = 'D:\vim73-x64\vimfiles\ftplugin\pydiction\complete-dict'
   let g:pydiction_menu_height = 20
   ```

When I open a python file with gvim, type `input os.p` and press `tab`, there is no autocompletion. Why?

Comment: Did you import the `os` module?

Comment: i am sure that os module is imported.

Answer (score 1):

- **Never** do anything in Vim's runtime files. All your customization happens in `$HOME`:

  ```
  $HOME\vimfiles\
  $HOME\_vimrc
  ```
- The `pydiction.vim` script is supposed to be here:

  ```
  $HOME\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\pydiction.vim
  ```
- `complete-dict` and `pydiction.py` can be anywhere. You could very well put them together with `pydiction.vim`:

  ```
  $HOME\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\complete-dict
  $HOME\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\pydiction.py
  ```

  or somewhere else:

  ```
  $HOME\vimfiles\pydiction\complete-dict
  $HOME\vimfiles\pydiction\pydiction.py
  ```
- `set filetype=python` has nothing to do in your `_vimrc`: `filetype plugin on` already deals with filetype recognition for you *and* it doesn't work anyway.